# How to change "View" popup when user left context card for CardService app script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to find some information how could I put some text into popup when user left mail context by clicking on "Back" button. Maybe someone faced with the same problem?

[image][image]

I search this info in documentation but can't find anything.

Comment: Can you post your script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. If you has the same problem - just add [setPeekCardHeader](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/card-builder#setpeekcardheaderpeekcardheader) to the card